# Eclipse 4 Injecting an OSGI Service

Tags: java, eclipse, dependency-injection, e4

I want to turn a `Settings` class into an OSGI declarative service which e4 can inject.

I have created the service in *OSGI-INF/settingsService.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="org.eclipse.recommenders.privacy.rcp">
        <implementation class="org.eclipse.recommenders.privacy.rcp.PrivacySettingsService"/>
    <service>
        <provide interface="org.eclipse.recommenders.privacy.rcp.IPrivacySettingsService"/>
    </service>
</scr:component>
```

And I have annotated the variable with `@Inject` as described here:
http://toedter.com/2010/06/28/eclipse-4-0-dependency-injection-and-osgi-declarative-services/

```
@Inject
private IPrivacySettingsService privacySettingsService;
```

But I am getting a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Where are you trying to do the @Inject? Is this an object that the application model knows about (MPart, Handler, ...) or some object of your own?

Comment: It's my own object. You can find the code in github: https://github.com/yaziza/org.eclipse.recommenders.privacy/blob/master/plugins/org.eclipse.recommenders.privacy.rcp/src/org/eclipse/recommenders/privacy/rcp/ApprovalDialogJob.java

Comment: Injection is not done on your own objects unless you create them with `ContextInjectionFactory.make` or force injection with `ContextInjectionFactory.inject`.

Comment: Greg-449 is right, when you create your UIJob by calling its constructor, nothing will be injected into it.  He should post an answer.

Comment: Check if your plug-in exporting the service has a "Service-Component: my-component-def.xml" entry in the MANIFEST.MF. Also it has to be marked as "Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your code, your problem seems to be, that you are creating the `ApprovalDialogJob` with the `new` operator. This way the DI engine will not manage the object, hence it will not inject any values.

You need to use the `ContextInjectionFactory` to create your class:

```
ApprovalDialogJob job = new ApprovalDialogJob(extensionReader);
ContextInjectionFactory.inject(job, eclipseContext);
```

Where eclipseContext is an instance of `IEclipseContext`, which you can either obtain by injecting it into `Startup` or by using:

```
BundleContext bundleContext = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(Startup.class).getBundleContext();
IEclipseContext context = EclipseContextFactory.getServiceContext(bundleContext);
```

Hope this helps.